# how to post on facebook wall without dialog from android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Now I am developing some app containing quotes and I want make ability to share any quote on my facebook wall

I am using sdk 3 and I can make login but I can't post on wall without dialog ??

This is my post function :-

```
private void PublishToFeedInBackground() {

    final Bundle _postParameter = new Bundle();
    _postParameter.putString("name", "ahmed");
    _postParameter.putString("link", "eew");
    _postParameter.putString("picture", "ew");
    _postParameter.putString("caption", "we");
    _postParameter.putString("message", "efwefwefwe");
    _postParameter.putString("description", "few");


    final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_stream");

    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
        NewPermissionsRequest reauthRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(reauthRequest);
    }

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", _postParameter, HttpMethod.POST);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what dialog is coming??

Comment: i don't want any dialog ... i just want to post on wall directly

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"feed" parameters:fbArguments HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}];
```

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBRequestConnection#startWithGraphPath%3Aparameters%3AHTTPMethod%3AcompletionHandler%3A)